# Is using eval() in this case a good idea in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, eval

I am working on a chess game in pygame, and I came up with an idea to `blit` chess piece images onto the screen with following "logic":

```
for field in fields:
   window.blit(eval(f"{field.get_piece().get_colour()}_{field.get_piece().__class__.__name__.lower()}"), (field.x, field.y))
```

where `get_piece()` and `get_colour()` are just simple get methods to return `Piece object` and `colour` respectfully. `Piece` can be `Pawn`, `King`, `Queen`, etc.
Pygame `surface` objects are named using pattern `piece_colour` + `_` + `class_name`. So `eval()` gets the job done.
And this way I've avoided writing multiple if statements.

Now I'm interested if this is acceptable (good) solution and ofcourse what are better ways to do this. Thanks!

Comment: It just doesn't seem necessary; why don't you use a dictionary mapping piece and colour to the surface objects? `{('white', 'Pawn'): white_pawn, ...}`. Or maybe make it a property of the piece, so you can just `window.blit(field.surface, (field.x, field.y))`.

Comment: couldn't you just use `lambda` for that?

Comment: Thank you for responses. I thought of this and since I'm learning I've decided to ask for opinions. Dictionary is an excellent option, and I'm not sure how I would implement `lambda`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Actually it does, I searched but haven't found this one. Knew about security issues but wasn't aware it is slow. Thanks.